CIFS on 22.04 LTS - has something changed between kernel 5.15.0-101-generic and 5.15.0-102-generic?
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 client connected via CIFS to an Ubuntu 22.04 server.
The mounts are done via an fstab entry similar to:
//machine.fqdn/sharename /mnt/some.directory cifs rw,credentials=/root/some.file,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

I've updated both systems just now from 5.15.0-101-generic kernels to 5.15.0-102-generic .
The upgrade of the client seems to break the automatic mount.  Instead of the expected information, df returns:
df: /mnt/some.directory: Resource temporarily unavailable

instead of the expected:
//machine.fqdn/sharename    61608748 16429164  45179584  27% /mnt/some.directory

If I reboot the client off the previous 5.15.0-101-generic kernel all is well again.
This seems to be similar to the problem described at https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1bzshdt/ubuntu_2204_smb_shares_stopped_working_lastnight/?rdt=37907 , although there is no solution there yet.  With the problem kernel in place, attempted access to the share is "somewhat unreliable" - access via smbclient is mostly OK, but mounting via an fstab entry is not.  With the problematic kernel, the /etc/fstab entries in place and the disks not mounted, "mount /mnt/some.directory" returns no errors.
Is this some sort of known issue, or a documented change (perhaps to mount parameters) in kernel 5.15.0-102-generic ?
Edit: Looks like someone has logged it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/2060797 .  Also see https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=417371 .

If it's a kernel bug, we can't really do anything about it, except waiting for it to be fixed.

we had the same problem after OS updates. Our workaround was to switch cifs/smb protocol vers=3.0 back to vers=1.0. We are waiting for an update.

I had the same problem. Copying a large file using DoubleCMD or Nemo LM21.3,
from one NAS share to another NAS share resulted in a '0' bytes file.
I also returned to kernel 5.15.0-100-generic, and the problem was solved. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. Greet Tom

I have the same issues since a few days. My smb share access became very slow, and I tried to figure out what causes these problems. I saw a lot of smb request issues from the CIFS module (see below). I think the CIFS module in kernel version 5.15 creates that trouble. The version 5.11 works fine for me!
Unfortunately, my only solution at the moment is to switch back to an older kernel version!
[31940.114972] CIFS: fs/cifs/readdir.c: fce error -2
[31940.624368] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: -104
[31940.624432] CIFS: fs/cifs/readdir.c: fce error -2
[31941.124821] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: 0
[31941.634623] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: -104
[31942.095318] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31942.113932] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: 0
[31942.136770] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0xc0000016 to POSIX err -5
[31942.595203] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31942.635067] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: -104
[31942.654499] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0xc0000016 to POSIX err -5
[31943.100779] CIFS: fs/cifs/connect.c: Received no data or error: -104
[31943.121753] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0xc0000016 to POSIX err -5
[31943.586668] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31943.597555] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31943.602327] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31943.607955] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0x80000006 to POSIX err -61
[31943.608239] CIFS: fs/cifs/smb2maperror.c: Mapping SMB2 status code 0xc0000128 to POSIX err -9


For completeness, the 105 kernel was released and addressed the issues.
