Samba connection issues after the new 6.5.0-27-generic kernel update
All the systems that are facing the following issue are running Xubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I am using the following command to connect to samba shares:
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.../shareName mountPath -o rw,vers=default,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,username="username",password="password" --verbose

This command used to work flawlessly before the latest 6.5.0-27-generic kernel update.
Now, although it creates a successful connection, whenever I'm accessing files from the client computer's thunar I see at least a dozen messages like the ones below, in the server's journal.log:
pam_unix(samba:session): session opened for user xxxxxxx(uid=xxx) by (uid=0)
pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user xxxxxxx

The samba session is closed and reopened continuously for as long as I keep accessing files from the client computer.
Also, the following message appeared on the client computer's journal.log once:
CIFS: reconnect tcon failed rc=-11

The messages above do not appear if I make the initial share connection using thunar instead of mount.cifs.
How can this be fixed please?
Thank you.

Sounds a bit like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/2060797 ; see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1509987/cifs-on-22-04-lts-has-something-changed-between-kernel-5-15-0-101-generic-and?noredirect=1#comment2649875_1509987 which I asked yesterday,

It seems the new update has definitely created some issues. I think a new update will be relased quite soon.

After the installation of the new 6.5.0-28-generic kernel that was just released, the log messages do not appear any more.
It looks like the error has been corrected.

i have the same problem that i described here
unresponding cp between two remote cifs share, both on the same distant machine
for the moment, waiting the kernel correction, i follow this to downgrade kernel ; Version 6.5.0-26 is working well
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/

The 6.5.0-27-x kernel has a back ported patch that breaks cifs functionality (filemap_get_folio works differently between several kernel versions).
More info here:
https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg524738.html
